# How to let Kubernetes pod run a local script

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I want to run a local script within Kubernetes pod and then set the output result to a linux variable

Here is what I tried:

```
# if I directly run -c "netstat -pnt |grep ssh", I get output assigned to $result:

cat check_tcp_conn.sh 
#!/bin/bash
result=$(kubectl exec -ti <pod_name> -- /bin/bash -c "netstat -pnt |grep ssh")
echo "result is $result"
```

What I want is something like this:

```
#script to be called:
cat netstat_tcp_conn.sh
#!/bin/bash
netstat -pnt |grep ssh

#script to call netstat_tcp_conn.sh:
cat check_tcp_conn.sh 
#!/bin/bash
result=$(kubectl exec -ti <pod_name> -- 
/bin/bash -c "./netstat_tcp_conn.sh)
echo "result is $result
```

the result showed `result is /bin/bash: ./netstat_tcp_conn.sh: No such file or directory`.

How can I let Kubernetes pod execute netstat_tcp_conn.sh which is at my local machine?

Comment: you need to somehow mount the script within the running pod, check for different ways of mounting the script within a pod.

Comment: Krishna: I know we can use -v in docker to mount, or configure mount in k8s configuration file. But how to mount a local file from Kubernetes exec command directly?

Comment: I don't think we can do that from the exec command. I believe we need to mount the file first and then run exec as it is or may be use mix of `cat` and `xargs` to pass the output of the file directly to the `exec` command.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use following command to execute your script in your pod:

```sh
kubectl exec POD -- /bin/sh -c "`cat netstat_tcp_conn.sh`"
```

Comment: @Ali Tou how this command will execute if `netstat_tcp_conn.sh` dosen't exists inside pod or it exists inside pod?

Comment: @heheh it doesn't depend on the contents of the pod at all. That `cat netstat_tcp_conn.sh` will be evaluated by your shell on client-side, before running `kubectl exec`.

Comment: You 're the best, thanx

Comment: @AliTou Is there a way to pass an argument to the script while executing it in the mentioned manner?

Comment: @ElvinVarghese I don't think so. The only thing comes to my mind is that you can set environment variables before running that command so that some variables substitutions can be done. I don't have anything else of passing a variable to that script.

Comment: @AliTou Thanks for reply. I tried with "foo=bar && `cat script.sh`", and value seems to be getting passed on to the script.

Answer (score 3):

You can copy local files into pod using kubectl command like kubectl cp /tmp/foo :/tmp/
Then you can change its permission and make it executable and run it using kubectl exec.

Comment: Thanks Rushikesh. I decide to use Ali's solution. but cp should work as well.